# simple MOSFET analog multiplexer

Tags: analog, multiplexer

In my project, the 4051 switches two signal sources routed to the 4024 counter - an external clock signal and a manual advance clock (tactile switch). I thought that the use of the 4051 was overkill, so I would like to replace the 4051 with a simple analogue multiplexer. I had the idea to use two n-MOSFETs. In the simulation, the system works, are there any errors, something that needs to be corrected? The grey area is the original part of the design.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use p-channel MOSFET's.

Look at this link for the correct circuit topology:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvvo4.png

Comment: Working perfect, thank you.